# Firefox extension: apply content_scripts on all web pages but css on specific web page?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, firefox-addon, manifest.json

I have a **Firefox** extension where I want to apply `contentScript.js` to **all web pages**. The `manifest.json` looks like this:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "css": ["background.css"],
      "js":["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ]
```

However, I **only** want the CSS to be applied to a certain web page. Right now the CSS is applied to all web pages.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend came up with a solution, change your manifest file to this:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js":["contentScript.js"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.website.org/*"],
      "css": ["background.css"]
    }
  ]
```

Life saver.